# node.js WebSocket Server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

currently i try to create a push server instance for new activities around our database. Of course, you find a lot of information about this topic.

I'm using:
http://static.brandedcode.com/nws-docs/#s6-p1

With the following client implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var webSocket = new io.Socket('ws//test', {
                    port: 8080
                });

                webSocket.connect();

                webSocket.on('connect',function() {
                    console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
                });

                webSocket.on('message',function(data) {
                    console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
                });

                webSocket.on('disconnect',function() {
                    console.log('The client has disconnected!');
                });

                window.ws = webSocket;
            }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The console returns:

```
Unexpected response code: 404
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ws//test:8080/socket.io/xhr-polling//1303822796984. Origin http://test is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
1303822796984GET http://ws//test:8080/socket.io/xhr-polling//1303822796984 undefined (undefined)
```

I don't know the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Greets!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You´re trying to connect directly to a WebSocket server using Socket.io.
If you are running only a WebSocket server and not the Socket.io server, the you can use the normal HTML5 API to connect to websockets.

for example:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://domain:port");
ws.onopen = function(){}
ws.onmessage = function(m){}
ws.onclose = function(){}
```

What browser are you using?
WebSockets are currently only supported by Google Chrome. Tests in other browsers will fail.

Comment: what if i want to send a message without having to rely on `onmessage` events and such?

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted `'ws://push.xxx.binder.test'` instead of `'ws//push.xxx.binder.test'` (missing colon).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var webSocket = new io.Socket('ws//push.xxx.binder.test', {
```

to

```
var webSocket = new io.Socket('push.xxx.binder.test', {
```

You no need to add prefix for your domain for socket.io (especially without colon before slashes). Also `var webSocket` isn't good naming - socket.io can use not only `websockets` (even in your errors it using `xhr-poliing`)